# Why do I need 2 resistors to divide voltage?

Tags: voltage, resistors

I know someone else asked the same question, but I wasn't able to understand it.

My question is, why do you need 2 resistors (1 to ground), to divide the voltage?

Just 1 resistor would do the same task.
Suppose I have 9V and want to get 5V. I could do it with 1 resistor, too.
Excuse my ignorance, I'm not experienced.

[image].

Comment: yes, you still have two resistors ... the load is the R2

Comment: @jsotola: what load?

Comment: @Curd, the load is the device that is requiring the 5 V supply

Comment: This is a voltage divider. It has two resistors. What is the question, exactly? If you draw your proposed voltage divider with one resistor, it will be easier to explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: _"Suppose I have 9V and want to get 5V. I could do it with 1 resistor"_ - I tested your theory with a 9V battery. With no resistor it read 9.18V on my multimeter. Then I put 1 resistor in series and it still read 9.18V. "Perhaps the 1 resistor is too small", I thought. So I tried the biggest 1 I had (3" long and 1/3" diameter). Nope, still 9.18V. Seems 1 resistor is not enough...

Comment: There are plenty of good bits  in the below answers, so I'll just comment that if you need 5V from 9V, a voltage divider with resistors is (almost) never the right way to do it. Look at regulators.

Comment: It's common sense: if you didn't have 2 resistors, then Vout would either be shorted to Vin or GND. In which case it would naturally have the same potential as either Vin or GND, rather than the 3rd potential you wish to create.

Comment: @jsotola: what device?

Comment: One resistor wont cut it because the voltage drop is 100% across a single resistor...  two resistors, one fed from supply and one from ground and you can have a voltage ratio.

Comment: "Just 1 resistor would do the same task." -- How, exactly? What sort of a configuration are you thinking of? It's hard to tell what your assumptions are and what situations you've already considered if you don't tell them.

Answer (score 19):

If you have one resistor and no load, then the 9v in will give you 9v at the other end.

If you have any sort of load, then that's behaving like your second resistor. Note that as the load changes, the division ratio and so the load voltage changes. That's one of the reasons why we tend not to use single resistors for dropping the voltage into a load.

Answer (score 14):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Ikbn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Various loads on a series resistor.*

- (a) \$V_O = V_{IN}\$ as there is no current flowing.
- (b)  The lamp forms the second resistor R2 in your schematic. This will work as the lamp resistance will be consistent once the initial warm-up has taken place.
- (c) The motor voltage will vary with load. Increase the load and it will slow down, its back-EMF will decrease lowering its apparent resistance and lowering \$V_O\$.
- (d) Varying R5 will cause \$V_O\$ to vary.

So the answer is that sometimes you can omit your R2 but you have to understand the implications. Even when R2 is there you need to be aware that with a low resistance load the load on the divider will increase and the voltage will drop from the unloaded value.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: I'm just wondering why you modified my HTML markdown to MathJAX? Did it not render properly for you?

Comment: Honestly, it appears to me that SE is now ordering answers on the page by modification time rather than upvotes. I upvoted your answer and wanted to get it moved higher on the page. It looks like some users may be gaming the system to get upvotes on answers that are just reiteration of existing answers.

Answer (score 9):

Resistors only drop voltage if current flows through them and the amount dropped depends on the current. Assuming your load draws zero current, which is a good approximation of most voltage inputs (which your Vout feeds into), without R2 no current flows through R1 so no voltage drops across R1 so the voltage on both sides of R1 are the same.

Comment: Exactly... the role of the second resistor is to provide the current... It is also interesting to replace it with a current source...

Comment: That’s what all the other answers fail to point out: A voltage divider assumes zero “external” load on Vout.

Comment: Quote: "Resistors only drop voltage if current flows through them and the amount dropped depends on the current"......DKNguyen - may I ask you: What do you think about my comment below circuifanatsist`s contribution?

Comment: @LvW sounds like semantics to me.

Comment: @DKNguyen...yes, I agree -  for a practical engineer (design only) it is always sufficient to think "current produces voltage". (You say: Semantics). However, from time to time, I think, it is good and necessary to recall physical laws. Why not? It certainly helps to improve understanding of technical phenomenons...you are not a lecturer, correct?

Comment: @lvw Not a lecturer but I think it's just kind of like saying there is voltage with no current. There's always some miniscule current or else you wouldn't be able to measure anything. I think we all know that in the back of our mind.

Comment: But that is a complete other problem (miniscule current) which - in my opinion - has nothing to do with the original question "does a current need a driving voltage or can a current produce a voltage". We should not mix two different problems.

Comment: @Lvw My point is its the same type of language. I've also yet to see you provide an alternate phrasing legible to a beginner.

Comment: DKNguyen..but at least you see my point, ok? I agree - it is not of great importance. (Another - more "critical" - example for "laboratory jargon" is the assertion "Ib determins/controls Ic" -  but, please, do not answer to this point...you knnow why...)

Answer (score 6):

If you divide anything, you always get at least two parts.

Also a voltage divider must consist of two parts, one for the first voltage and one for the second voltage.

That‘s why there are two resistors involved.

Comment: It is interesting that the part responsible for the first voltage is not simply R1 but R1 + R2 while the part responsible for the second voltage is only R2. What is even more interesting, is how to make only R1 to be responsible for the first voltage (how to remove R2)...

Comment: That's wrong: Both R1 and R2 are responsible for first and second voltage.

Comment: I mean that the first (input) voltage is applied across R1 + R2 and the second (output) voltage appears across R2.

Answer (score 6):

Once the role of the second resistor R2 has become clear (***to cause a current to flow through R1 and, accordingly, a voltage drop across it to be subtracted from the input voltage***), now we can combine the two resistors into one to get the so-called "potentiometer". Here is a 4-step scenario for "inventing" and investigating the famous device. It is extracted from [my Wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Walking_along_the_Resistive_Film) about Ohm's experiment (the pictures are drawn by me).

### Hydraulic analogy - Pressure diagram

**A tapped pipe (there is no flow).** Let's begin with considering a well-known hydraulic analogy (plumbing) - that we can see everywhere around us. For example, imagine a large vessel filled of water that supplies a long thin pipe; let's first the pipe to be tapped (Fig. 1). The question is: "What is the pressure inside the pipe?" And more precisely speaking, "What are the local pressures along the pipe?" There are not so many people that will answer rightly these simple questions.

[image: Pressure diagram of tapped pipe]

Fig. 1. The local pressures along the tapped pipe are equal to the input pressure.

We can get to know, if we drill small holes at equal intervals along the pipe (if we want to be more precise, we might stick vertically thin glass pipes acting as local manometers). The result is expectable for us: all the water levels (accordingly, all the local pressures along the pipe) are equal. This picture shows the pressure distribution along the pipe; we can name it "pressure diagram".

**An opened pipe (there is flow).** Now open the pipe (Fig. 2); the water will begin flowing. This is a well-known situation from our routine where someone opens a faucet somewhere in the end of the plumbing. At the left end the water pressure is maximum; at the right end it is minimum. But what are the local pressures along the pipe now? Our intuition suggests that the local pressures will decrease gradually from left to the right.

[image: Pressure diagram of open pipe]

Fig. 2. The local pressures along the opened pipe decrease gradually.

Really, the levels of the water bars (accordingly, the local pressures along the pipe) decrease gradually from left to the right. The envelope of the pressure diagram is a triangle.

### Electrical domain - Voltage diagram

Let's now transfer these notions to our electrical domain, in order to see if the voltages along a resistive wire are distributed in the same way. That means to reproduce the genuine Ohm's experiment under the conditions of today.

Now, fix the two ends of a wire in porcelain insulated terminals (holders) and apply voltage (for instance, 10 V) first to the left end of the wire (Fig. 3).

[image: Investigating the local voltages along a wire]

Fig. 3. Investigating the local voltages along a wire

What can we investigate now in this arrangement? What do we measure with the voltmeter? The usual viewpoint is to think of a resistor as of a point, as of something that has not dimensions, as of a two-terminal element that has only a property of resistance. But here we have the unique chance to peep inside the "resistor"! What will you "see" along the wire? What will the voltmeter show when we slide its active probe from right to left? What are the local voltages along a resistor, if there is no current - zero, 10 V or something else?

**An opened circuit (there is no current).** Remember what a resistor does - it "resists". What does it resist? It resists, obstructs, disturbs current by dissipating power. But no current flows in an open circuit. So, there is nothing to resist; as though, the resistor is not a resistor but "conductor" that transfers the entire voltage from the left to right end.

[image: Voltage diagram of open circuit]

Fig. 4. The local voltages along the resistive film of an opened circuit are the same.

We can apply the idea of a pressure diagram to present in a similar way the voltage distribution along the resistive wire. We can think of voltage as a kind of pressure; so, we may present the local voltages by local voltage bars in exactly the same way as we presented the local pressures by local water bars (Fig. 4)! As above, the lengths of the voltage bars are proportional to the magnitudes of the local voltages regarding to ground (we might set the zero voltage level at the height of the resistor and then to draw the positive voltage bars above and the negative voltage bars below the resistor's level). The set of these voltage bars forms the whole voltage diagram. We can use the envelope of the voltage diagram instead the set of voltage bars to simplify the image.

**Closing the circuit.** Now, ground the right end of the wire. Move the voltmeter probe along the wire and measure the local voltage drops; Ohm did exactly the same. He moved the probe from one position to other, measured the corresponding potentials, made the difference between them and calculated the ratio (V2 - V1)/(L2 - L1) = (V2 - V1)/(r2 - r1) = dV/dR = I. Thus he has established that this ratio (it was the current I) is constant along the wire; so, Ohm has concluded that V/R = I. We can see that, when moving the voltmeter probe, voltage drops decrease gradually from 10 to 0 volts; accordingly, the bars of our voltage diagram decrease their length gradually (Fig. 5).

[image: Voltage diagram of closed circuit]

Fig. 5. The local voltages along the resistive film of a closed circuit decrease gradually.

We can draw such a picture for every real conductor with some resistance that convey big current to a powerful load (Fig. 6).

[image: Voltage distribution along a line]

Fig. 6. Voltage distribution along a line

Comment: To go a little beyond the actual topic: Fig. 5 and Fig. 6 clearly show that - physically speaking - we cannot say that the current through a resistor would cause a voltage drop. This is "laboratory jargon". The current through a resistor always needs an electric field (i.e. a voltage) inside the resistor to allow the electrons to move.

Comment: @ LvW Figuratively speaking, the current is only the "transmission" for the "force" of voltage...

Comment: If "current is...the transmission for...voltage" then why does a voltage change travel millions of times faster than the charge flows? If a resistor is not a resistor if no current is flowing through it, then what is it? What kind of symbol do we use for it in a schematic? Does Ohm's Law still apply? How can shops sell "resistors" if they don't have any current flowing through them when I buy them? Does that mean a valve is not a valve unless it is under pressure?

Comment: Then what is the current function in circuits? What else can it be other than a carrier? As for the resistor, if its resistance is negligible compared to the load resistance (that is infinitely high in this case - open circuit), then we can consider the resistor as a conductor. You can draw a circuit on a piece of paper using a soft graphite pencil and you can think of  the graphite lines as of conducting "wires"... if only the load is high resistive. Replace the floating resistor with a piece of wire and measure the voltage again... it would be the same... so they are the same in this case...

Comment: The flow of current can transmit **power** but it does not **transmit voltage**. That is a horrible misconception that needs to be stamped out forever.

Comment: You said "no current flows in an open circuit..as though, the resistor is not a resistor but "conductor" that transfers the entire voltage from the left to right end." How can you say that an **open circuit** is the same as a **conductor**? How can you say that a resistor **transfers voltage**? This is very confusing language.

Comment: The circuit is open in the place of the load (missing R2)... and there is only one branch - the resistor R1. Its left (input) end is at voltage V and its right (output) end is floating... and I'm thinking about what's going on here. I see the output voltage is the same as the input voltage; so, I think, the resistor has transferred the voltage from the input to the output... as though it is a piece of wire. So, if the load has extremely high resistance, the connecting wires can be resistors... acting as conductors. The same situation is with Rc in the CE stage when the transistor is cut off...

Comment: What do you have against "voltage transfer"? How do I say that the same voltage appears at the output? Maybe "deliver" or "convey"? They say "transfer ratio". We can think of this arrangement as of a degenerate voltage divider with transfer ratio of 1. It is important for students to understand why the output voltage equals the input voltage. I have noted that most of them think it is zero "because there was a resistor that reduced it". I also continue thinking about this phenomenon and looking for better explanation.

Comment: It is also interesting that if we connect a perfect voltmeter across the branch (R1), and it shows zero voltage, we cannot say what the reason is since the voltage depends both on the resistance and current (V = I.R). So, we can think the zero resistance (R1 = 0, piece of wire) is the reason... but actually the zero current (R2 = infinity, open circuit) is the reason...

Comment: "perfect voltmeter" "shows zero voltage"..."the zero current...infinity, open-circuit...is the reason". If there is an **open circuit** then there is no reason to expect that there will be zero voltage between the two points. Ohm's Law **does not apply** to an open circuit. If you assume **infinite** resistance and **zero** current you **can not** multiply and get any valid result for the voltage. I know what you meant, but beginners will be confused by this kind of language.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, I have said in the other comment what beginners need above all - imagination, intuition, associations, thought and real experiments, human attitude to them with many explanations of the phenomena from different perspectives, richly illustrated but not ascetic white&black circuit diagrams... a rich environment in which notions about invisible electrical phenomena mature... This is best seen in the questions they ask here... If everything was the way you present it, they wouldn't ask such questions...

Answer (score 4):

Because if you do it with 1 resistor, **it's not a voltage divider anymore. It's something else**.  And as a result, all the rules you learned about voltage dividers won't work.

The major feature of a resistor ladder / voltage divider is that it gives a quasi-correct voltage *when quiescent* i.e. with no load being drawn from V<sub>out</sub>.  A reasonable amount of load from V<sub>out</sub> will also cause a reasonable voltage at the tap.  The load is influencing the voltage, because it is in parallel with R2, so its effective conductance (1/resistance) will add to R2's conductance (1/resistance).

[image]

However with R1 and R2 selected sensibly relative to all possible ranges of load current, the tapped voltage will remain in reasonable limits.

You want to junk the whole idea of a voltage divider by getting rid of R2.  Now, the load is not in series with R2, so the load's effective resistance will add to R1 to decide the voltage at the tap point.  The load's current draw (the more it draws the lower its effective resistance), will cause wild shifts in inlet voltage.  If the load's current draw nears zero, R1's voltage drop stops being much at all, and the inlet voltage nears the supply voltage.

So "dump the ladder; hot to resistor to load to return" only works with loads of reasonably well-known impedance.  However, the entire circuit must be ready to experience full system voltage.

A great example of this is an old streetcar headlight resistor; it uses a large resistor box "R1" (placed in the motorman's compartment to heat the compartment) to drop 600V down to the 32V needed for the headlight.  So normally R1 is dropping 568 volts.  When the headlight burns out, motormen think "I'll change that! 32 volts from ground isn't dangerous!"  Now how much voltage is actually on that socket? If R1 was dropping 568 volts at (let's say) 5.68 amps, how much is R1 dropping at 0 amps?  Anyone? Anyone? Bueller?  That's right.  `E=IR`, E=0 when I=0 regardless of R. So with R1 dropping 0V, the voltage at the headlight socket is 600V.  *It better be insulated for that*.

Answer (score 4):

You should never feel ashamed for trying to know better about something. no matter your technical level.
A simple answer would be: voltage is divided by series. Ideally, when you have only 1 resistor in parallel with the Power supply, its voltage is equal to its power supply's voltage only. Every time you add a resistor in series, the voltage gets divided among these resistors.(ergo the voltage divider rule). So in your case, it would be 9V. You should recheck your circuit for a possible mistake.
Also, on real-life circuits, the resistance of the cable is taken into account to be in series with the load's resistance. so you can have 5V using 1 resistor only if you have a very long and thin wire, or a very large current.

Comment: +1 for the courage and confidence... Really, we can see two dividers here - a resistive divider with ratio of R2/(R1 + R2) and a voltage divider with ratio of V2/(V1 + V2). If the resistance is linear, there is even third "geometrical" divider with ratio of L2/(L1 + L2). All they are "syncronized" -  R2/(R1 + R2) = V2/(V1 + V2) = L2/(L1 + L2)...

Answer (score 2):

> why do you need 2 resistors (1 to ground), to divide the voltage?

One resistor can be used to *drop* voltage (if the load draws current) but to *divide* voltage you need something to create a division ratio. To be a voltage *divider* the output voltage needs to be a constant *proportion* of the input voltage. So a voltage divider that drops 9 V to 5 V should also drop 18 V to 10 V, 90 V to 50 V etc. always maintaining the same division ratio.

The only thing that can do that is another resistor (or a load which acts like a resistor, and so effectively is one). Why? Because to maintain the division ratio you need a second component which has the same property of proportionality between voltage and current as R1 - in other words, another resistor.

Note that this need for two resistors only applies to DC. In an AC circuit capacitors and inductors have [reactance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance), which is like resistance but varies with frequency. In an AC circuit you can have a capacitor or inductor voltage divider, which works just like the resistor divider except that it uses two capacitors or two inductors.

Comment: Interesting things can be seen in this humble 2-resistor network... For example, we can see two functional blocks - a 'voltage-to-current converter' (R1 + R2) and the dual 'current-to-voltage converter' (R2). They are nested here like a Russian 'matryoshka'; that's why the division ratio is not simply R2/R1 but R2/(R1 + R2). It is interesting to see how can we simplify it to be the neat R2/R1... and to represent the network by two separate cascaded converters - V-to-I (R1) and I-to-V (R2)...